# Xcode 7 webkit causes thread 1: signal SIGABRT error

Tags: c, xcode, web, browser

I downloaded Xcode 7 to my mac to make a web browser using the webkit feature. I started working on the basic layout, and it worked well. I then added the webkit element to my window, and when I tested it, I got this: 
[[Image] The code that contains the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J4mD.png)

I have tried many things such as checking the outlets, but nothing has worked. All help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to put code along with the question instead of putting a link.

Comment: I tried but It wouldn't show the error...

Comment: This error is meaningless as showing top level only. It's pretty much like "there is an error in your program".

Comment: I'm afraid that is the entire program.

Comment: There is an `NSApplicationMain` implementation somewhere, isn't it?